# shortest way to pass a list of BOOL's to a method in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, boolean

What's the shortest way to pass a list of BOOL's to a method in objective-c?  (i.e. without having to set up entries in an NSArray using NSNumber to wrap them).

Background:  I want to call a test method many times in a unit test so want a shorthand way to effectively say:

```
[myCustomObject compareWithBools:[TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE]]
```

In the receiving method "compareWithBools" I can put in the lines of code to massage back to be able to compare, however just wanted a nice short line within the tests I can call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skip the `NSNumber` wrapper with a macro?

```
#define Greg_BOOLFromNSString(s) ([(s) isEqualToString:@"YES"])

[myCustomObject compareWithStrings:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"YES", @"NO", @"YES", @"YES", @"YES", nil]];
```

Comment: this looks quite good Josh  - would it be betting adding the Greg_BOOLFromNSString using categories to be an extension method for NSString perhaps?

Comment: Marked as answer noting the compactness of the last line, and the fact it is very readable even though compact.

Comment: @Greg: yes, you could certainly make it a method instead of a macro; this way does avoid a somewhat superfluous method call though.

Answer (score 4):

this approach is fairly easy

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareWithBools:(BOOL*)bools /* << a pointer to an array of BOOLs, which is owned by the caller */
                                 count:(NSUInteger)count; /* << the number of elements in @a bools */
```

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion.  Remember that Obj-C is a superset of C and a BOOL is just an integer.  So passing a C array of BOOLs is easy to do.

Comment: sorry didn't quite get it - are you saying to write a custom method somehow here?  compareWithBools isn't an existing method is it?

Comment: @Greg correct, and no, it is not an existing method (that i am aware of). based on the wording of the OP, i figured that was your intention. i added `NSComparisonResult` as the return type because `compareWith...:` methods *typically* return a comparison result.

Answer (score 2):

Pass an integer and compare separate bits of that integer:

```
[myCustomObject compareWithBools:13]; // which will be a sequence of 1011
```

Comment: oh :), that's really short - I kind of wanted to be able to see the values more readily - is there a way to do in base 2?  e.g. "compareWithBools:1011"?

Comment: You could write a macro BIN2INT(10011)

Comment: by macro is this just a #define you're referring to then Eimantas?

Comment: yes, I'm referring to define. Either that or a simple static function would work too.